# Three dimensional connectivity analysis in matlab 26 grayscale

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d

We are working on a grayscale image in three dimensions.

We received an exercise in processing medical images where the user presses a particular place and we need to paint the 26-degree neighbors who have the condition that they are close to ten percent of the selected pixel's color.

We wanted to know if there is an algorithm in matlab help to solve this exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Is this just a matter of iterating through the volume that encompasses the 26-degree neighborhood and deciding whether or not to paint the pixel?

In Matlab, you should be able to index the sub-volume and then directly apply the thresholding criterion.